# open div onclick and close others

Tags: jquery, css, slidedown, siblings, slideup

on my website I'm using several divs called "ligne".
inside those divs, I have 5 divs, and one of those divs ".content" is hidden.
when clicking on ".ligne", it shows the hidden div ".content" of the clicked ".ligne".
and when clicking on another ".ligne", it close all ".content" which are openned, and show the hidden div ".content" of the clicked ".ligne".

it's important that when clicking inside the '.content' the content does not slideUp.

My problem is that when a ".content" is opened, I would like to close the oppened ".content", when clicking again on the ".ligne", but not inside the ".content".

It works, it close the ".content", but the oppen it again.

here is a jsfiddle to see it in action :

http://jsfiddle.net/L9tr0uyq/

here is my html :

```
<div class="row ligne">

    <div class="col-xs-3 nom">TEST 1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 annee">2010</div>  
    <div class="col-xs-3 statut">BUILT</div> 
    <div class="col-xs-3 type">LIVE</div> 
    <div class="col-xs-12 content">


Inter haec Orfitus praefecti potestate regebat urbem aeternam ultra modum delatae dignitatis sese efferens insolenter, vir quidem prudens et forensium negotiorum oppido gnarus, sed splendore liberalium doctrinarum minus quam nobilem decuerat institutus, quo administrante seditiones sunt concitatae graves ob inopiam vini: huius avidis usibus vulgus intentum ad motus asperos excitatur et crebros.
</div>

  </div>

  <div class="row ligne">

    <div class="col-xs-3 nom">TEST 2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 annee" data-annee="2013-12-09">2013</div>  
    <div class="col-xs-3 statut">ON GOING</div> 
    <div class="col-xs-3 type">LEISURE</div> 
    <div class="col-xs-12 content">


Inter haec Orfitus praefecti potestate regebat urbem aeternam ultra modum delatae dignitatis sese efferens insolenter, vir quidem prudens et forensium negotiorum oppido gnarus, sed splendore liberalium doctrinarum minus quam nobilem decuerat institutus, quo administrante seditiones sunt concitatae graves ob inopiam vini: huius avidis usibus vulgus intentum ad motus asperos excitatur et crebros.

</div>

  </div>

  <div class="row ligne">

    <div class="col-xs-3 nom">TEST 3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 annee" data-annee="2013-11-04">2013</div>  
    <div class="col-xs-3 statut">ON GOING</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 type">MOVE</div> 
    <div class="col-xs-12 content">


Inter haec Orfitus praefecti potestate regebat urbem aeternam ultra modum delatae dignitatis sese efferens insolenter, vir quidem prudens et forensium negotiorum oppido gnarus, sed splendore liberalium doctrinarum minus quam nobilem decuerat institutus, quo administrante seditiones sunt concitatae graves ob inopiam vini: huius avidis usibus vulgus intentum ad motus asperos excitatur et crebros.

</div>
  </div>
```

my css :

```
body {font-size:12px;line-height:16px;}

.row.ligne {border-top:1px solid black;cursor:pointer}
.content {display:none}
.title {position: absolute;cursor:pointer}
.titre {position:fixed;width:100%;background-color:white;z-index:100}
#index {padding-top:16px;}
```

and my Jquery :

```
$('body').on('click', '.ligne', function () {

  $(this).siblings().children(".content").slideUp(300);
  $(this).children(".content").slideDown(300);

});


$('body').on('click', '.ligne .col-xs-3', function () {

  $(".content").slideUp(300)

});
```

Comment: I would add a new special class on click and then on the click of that class, close it.

Comment: @Melissa can you help with details ?
I tried this but it's not working...
  $('body').on('click', '.ligne', function () {
      
    $(this).children(".col-xs-3").addClass("open");
    $(this).siblings().children(".content").slideUp(300);
    $(this).children(".content").slideDown(300);

  });


    $('body').on('click', '.open', function () {
          $(".col-xs-3").removeClass('open');

    $(".content").slideUp(300);


  });

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is that have to check if the content is visible, so you know whether you have to scroll up or down.

The second thing is that you click on a child element with class `content`, if so: return false.

As shown below:

```
$('body').on('click', '.ligne', function () {
  if ($(this).children(".content").is(":visible")) {
    $(this).children(".content").slideUp(300);
  } else {
    $(this).children(".content").slideDown(300);
  }
}).children().click(function(e) { // trigger click on children
    if ($(e.target).hasClass("content")) { // if e.target has the class '.content'
    return false; // dont do the code above '.children().click()'
  }
});
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/L9tr0uyq/8/)

Comment: thanks for your reply... what's the code at the end of your fiddle ?
$(document).click(function(event) { 
 if(!$(event.target).closest('.stap.set').length) {
  if($('.stap.set:not(.current)').is(":visible")) {
  $('.stap.set').find(".keuze-groep").slideUp(400);
  }
 }        
});

Comment: I removed that by now, it was something I used for a similar project I am currently working at. (Didn't want to lose the data and forgot to remove it after). Oops.

Comment: the problem is that when I click inside ".content", it close my div. I need to be able to add links and clickable content inside ".content" so when clicking inside content it needs to stay opened

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').on('click', '.ligne', function () {

  if(! $(this).hasClass('ouvert')) {
    $(this).siblings().children(".content").slideUp(300);
    $(this).children(".content").slideDown(300);
    $(this).addClass('ouvert');
  }

});


$('body').on('click', '.ligne.ouvert', function () {

  $(this).children(".content").slideUp(300);
  $(this).removeClass('ouvert');

});
```

If you were to update your code to the following, it would work. It's like the answer by Daan Heskes, but done with classes.

I prefer working with classes because it adds more sense to your source-code, which makes it easier to read by other developers.

http://jsfiddle.net/L9tr0uyq/9/

Comment: I don't see how your answer differs from mine. I'm only using classes.

Comment: I check for `hasClass('ouvert')`, you check for `is(':visible')`, so I add classes to the DOM which aren't actually necessary, but I prefer to add them because, at least to me, they make the code / DOM easier to read / understand.

Comment: You got it backwards buddy. You're adding unnessecary classes while you could also just simply check whether it's visible or not. `.is(':visible')` to me, is more understandable than `hasClass('ouvert')`. Because your way doesn't immediately tell another developer what you were actually checking for, because you use unneccesary classes. It only makes it so you have to understand (and find out) what `.ouvert` does. So other developers have to go and understand what this does as an extra step, while they likely already know what `.is(':visible')` checks for.

Comment: having a class `opened` on a div that opens and closes makes more sense to me :)

Comment: Then that's personal preference, but your statement that it'd be easier to read for *other* developers seems invalid to me.

Comment: I meant that it makes the pages source code, the DOM, would be easier to read. Because it's easier to understand which div is opened when it has the class opened.